# Show navbar menu item glyphicon only on mobile - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show the glyphicon next to my login button, only when the user is on mobile. I am using the visible-xs class for this however, the glyphicon is not aligned with the text when using any responsive utility.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in visible-xs"></span> Belépés</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using a custom class with display property set to inline:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .hidden-on-mobile{
        display: inline; !important;
    }
}
```